# Determine which RFID is closer

Tags: rfid

Apologies if this is a simple question, I'm very new to hardware. I'm wondering if using PN532 NFC/RFID controller (http://www.adafruit.com/products/364) I can determine which of two RFID tags is closer. Basically I want to identify which of two people is closer to the controller (they'd each have an rfid card with them).

Answer (score 2):

It's a **near-field** RFID reader - it'll probably work up to 0.1 metres with a passive tag. Trying to distinguish between two tags in a 0.1m maximum range will be nearly impossible with the chips that are used. Also, with two tags "stealing" magnetic energy from the field, the range might be much much smaller than 0.1 metres. Data collision detection and correction is also a really big-deal and I doubt there would be any that allows two tags to simultaneously communicate with the reader.

Comment: If it was *active* RFID, it would be different. You can guess location by varying your output power and transmitting that information along with the data sent. Then two or more receiving stations can work out approximate positions after a few packets...